# "if" clause inside event handler is not executed though the condition returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my `mouseenter` event handler.

```
.mouseenter(function(e) {
    console.log('enters');
    console.log('mouseDown: ' + mouseDown);
    if (mouseDown) {
       prepareStartPointPath();
       console.log('enters if');
    }
});
```

Something strange is going on here.

```
enters 
mouseDown: true
```

gets printed which means the code inside the if clause is not executed even though the condition is satisfied. What might be going on?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, step through your code. Don't ask others to do basic debugging on code that you wrote and they know noting about.

Comment: I have done that but was confused by different behaviours of different browsers. (I come from a Java background.) Thought somebody here would have had a similar experience. Found that the problem is in the `prepare...` method. Something is causing the method to end (without throwing exceptions or something.) Anyway, thanks for going through my code. You at least gave me some motivation.

Comment: Since you did not post the `prepare` method, it's hard to follow that explanation. If `console.log('mouseDown: ' + mouseDown);` executes and prints `'mouseDown: true'`, then there is literally nothing that would stop the following `if` body from executing, short of a browser crash.

Comment: I thought that was a possibility since the `prepare` method was not executing either. But now I have spotted the error in the method. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: And what was it? Now I'm curious.

Comment: An exception was thrown in `prepareStartPointPath()` and it stopped executing. It was a kind of `null pointer exception` thing. I fixed it and the code is now working.